# How to print tiff image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a html button to print a tiff image. When I click on the "Print" button a new window gets opened. Below is the code

```
    var printThis = "<img  src='image.tiff' width='100%'>"
    win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<html><head><style>body { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; }</style></head><body>');
    win.document.html(printThis);
    win.document.write('</body></html>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();
```

this code doesn't work as expected as it doesn't display the 'image.tiff' image.

If I replace "printThis" with this code

```
      var printThis = '<embed id="pre" access="4" src="' + imgName + '" type="image/tiff" width="100%" />';
```

It will display the image but if I print the page the image isn't printed.

I am using AlternaTIFF to show tiff images.
please suggest me solution for this. I am not getting answer on this.

Comment: Maybe your browsersettings/printsettings do not preview/print images or the path to the image in the popup is incorrect. Replace win.document.html with win.document.write.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `.write` then `.html` the `.write` again? 
Could you try:

`var printThis = "image.tiff"
    win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<html><head><style>body { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; }</style></head><body><img  src="' + printThis + '" width="100%"></body></html>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();`

Also, I tried and had an issue with the print pop-up that got stuck (in FF) making the browser spining continiusly - hense blocking the image from printing. I managed to click the `stop` button in the browser to free the pop-up and then everything printed fine. So you might want to look at the printing section of your scrip.